# Could not convert string to float while data preprocessing

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I need help with this. I'm a beginner and I am really confused with this. This is my code for the beginning of my preprocessing.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Import training set
dataset_train = pd.read_csv('Google_Stock_Price_Train.csv')
training_set = dataset_train.iloc[:, 1:6].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
training_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(training_set)
```

With this dataset(not full, I only put 10 of them as there are actually 10000)

> Date,   Open,  High,  Low,   Close,  Volume
>   1/3/2012,325.25,332.83,324.97,663.59,"7,380,500"
>   1/4/2012,331.27,333.87,329.08,666.45,"5,749,400"
>   1/5/2012,329.83,330.75,326.89,657.21,"6,590,300"
>   1/6/2012,328.34,328.77,323.68,648.24,"5,405,900"
>   1/9/2012,322.04,322.29,309.46,620.76,"11,688,800"
>   1/10/2012,313.7,315.72,307.3,621.43,"8,824,000"
>   1/11/2012,310.59,313.52,309.4,624.25,"4,817,800"
>   1/12/2012,314.43,315.26,312.08,627.92,"3,764,400"
>   1/13/2012,311.96,312.3,309.37,623.28,"4,631,800"

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-94c47491afd8>", line 3, in <module>
    training_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(training_set)

  File "C:\Users\MAx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 517, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)

  File "C:\Users\MAx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 308, in fit
    return self.partial_fit(X, y)

  File "C:\Users\MAx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 334, in partial_fit
    estimator=self, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)

  File "C:\Users\MAx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 433, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,770,000'
```

Sample code to help fix would be helpful

Comment: The problem is the comma in your numbers.

Comment: You mean i should put 1770000 instead?

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the commas in your numbers: `float("7,380,500")` fails.
I don't know how/if you can change the data, but if you can, `str.replace(',', '')` deletes all the commas from your number-strings. As your file is a `csv`, you need to make sure it only applies to the number-columns, not to all commas in your file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `'thousands'` param in the `'read_csv'`. This will format the data and remove the commas from between the numbers in 'Volume' column, and convert that to int (default) which can then be easily converted into float.

```
dataset_train = pd.read_csv('Google_Stock_Price_Train.csv', thousands=',')

dataset_train['Volume'].dtype
# Output: int64
```